# Small script to print file in Windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to learn how to send docx file to printing on the default printer on my computer.
I tried some options I found online but none of them could work for me.

If someone could share a small and simple code with explanation, I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to SO. please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Typically you would show what you have tried so far - presenting the code with a description of any error messages. If you have a look at this link - the second method may do what you want : https://wurstkoffer.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/c-printing-to-word-programmatically-in-3-way/ - if it doesn't come back with your code & do as explained.